# C# How to convert AnonymousType to generic parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I encountered a problem during writing a test for my ASP.NET Web Api project. In one function `public IHttpActionResult Get()` I am returning `return Json(new {  str = argString, argumentOne = args1.ToArray(), argumentTwo= arg2.ToArray()});`.

Now I try to write a test with mocks and I would like to check content of the result which is available if I did `var result = ctrl.Get() as JsonResult<MyType>;` but I have no type. When I am looking at type with debbuger I got this: `{System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<<>f__AnonymousType4<string, typesOne[], typesTwo[]>>}`. I tried dynamic and couple others which I found but none of those works.

Can someone explain to me what am I missing and give some goodies (tutorials, videos, githubs) with explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Create a data type to use for your method. e.g.:

```
public class MyJsonResult
{
    public string Str;
    public object ArgumentOne;
    public object ArgumentTwo;
}
```

*(Change the types of `ArgumentOne` and `ArgumentTwo` to whatever the types of the arrays you are using.)*

Use it like this:

```
return Json(new MyJsonResult() { 
        Str = argString, 
        ArgumentOne = args1.ToArray(), 
        ArgumentTwo = arg2.ToArray()});
```

Then you can put the type into your generic method like this:

```
var result = ctrl.Get() as JsonResult<MyJsonResult>;
```

Comment: Yeaa, I thought about it and even mentioned it. I thought there was some tricks about it because this method forces me to make some nice amount of classes :D but thanks!

Comment: @user3613919 Well alternatively you could use tuples, but using them in a variety of similar cases like it sounds like you are doing can lead to quite a bit of confusion if your code isn't exhaustively documented.